# Android implement left to right swipe animation

Tags: android, ios, animation, transition, left-to-right

In android, i want to move from current to previous activity by left to right swipe as in iOS. I want to be able to even hold while swiping such as both activities are visible at the same time.

I want to introduce transition/animation effect just like in [Telegram](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.messenger&hl=en) app. So please help how can i do it.
Tutorials or example code will work for me. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might have to use some combination of GestureDetector and custom activity finish animation to achieve this effect.

Comment: Try looking at http://androidexample.com/Swipe_screen_left__right__top_bottom/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=95&aaid=118

Comment: @ksarmalkar i also need to pause the animation in between while swiping such that both actcivities (previous & current) are visible at same time. This feature is same as provided in iOS by default.

Comment: Thats where the Gesture detector comes into play. So you need to combine "Gesture detector + custom activity animation" to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You better use the Swipe animation with multiple Fragments inside one Activity: [Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)

take a look at this tutorial : [HOW TO IMPLEMENT HORIZONTAL VIEW SWIPING WITH TABS](http://just-another-blog.net/programming/how-to-implement-horizontal-view-swiping-with-tabs/)

Comment: Thanks but my project if full of Activies and fragments and i need to apply swipe right on every screen. So i need a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using Google's NavComponent library, you should try a library that I wrote:

https://github.com/massivemadness/Fragula

It's fully integrated with NavComponent, which means the navigation API stays the same, you only need to make some changes in NavGraph and NavHost container.

Here's the result:

[image]